# Find exact item of list in a string

Tags: python

I have a problem of *false negative* during a loop in python.

That's my list:

```
l = ['modello', 'modello1', 'modello_old', 'new_modello']
```

and that's a string:

```
db = '/home/user/modello1.sqlite'
```

What I want to do is to filter the `db` string and to output the element of the list that appear in the string.

So the result should be **only** `modello1`.

This is my loop:

```
for i in l:
    if i in db:
        print i
```

but the result is not what I would like to obtain:

```
modello
modello1
```

how can I match the exact word?

**EDIT**: the problem could be that `db` is OS dependent so `/` could be transformed in `\`.

**EDIT2**: with @Karoly-Horvath solution:

transform the db in a list:

```
db = [os.path.basename(db).replace('.sqlite', '')]
```

loop the element of `db` in the whole list:

```
for i in db:
    if i in l:
        print i
```

Comment: use a regular expression

Comment: The only way I see this will be possible is if you split of the exact string you want to match with first. So split `db` into `modello1` however you see fit and then match it.

Comment: Well, the problem is that `modello` *does* appear in `db`; you should specify the rules for matching an element of `l` in `db`.

Comment: @Arcturus B, exactly, that's the problem! Splitting ``db`` could not be so easy because it is an ``sqlite`` file created on each computer.. so if one person uses Win I think the string will look differently (with backslashes)

Comment: Do you just want the filename, without the extension?

Comment: Sort the list of strings by length - from the longest to the shortest. Then, take only the first match (which is also the longest match)

Comment: If you analyze the complexity in the classic way, it can be done even faster without sorting the list, just iterate over the list, and whenever a string matches and is longer than the maximum length matched string, set it to be the maximum length matched string. It will cost `O(n)` instead of `O(nlogn)`

Comment: uhm.. why have you made `db` to a list? Why the extra indireciion? Your edit is very confusing.

Comment: so ``i`` become an element of a list and I can loop it.. without this transformation I wasn't able to create the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression or string functions to extract the relevant part:

```
m = os.path.basename(db).replace('.sqlite', '')  # 'modello1'
```

or (this was the original answer, only works for unix paths)

```
m = db.split('/')[-1].replace('.sqlite', '')     # 'modello1'
```

Now you can check for an exact match:

```
m in l   # True
```

Comment: Thanks... but the problem could be that the program I'm writing will run also in Windows machines, so ``db`` could have backslashes instead of normal ones.. In your answer you split ``db`` when it find ``/``.. Sorry if am not be so precise in my question..

Comment: OP wants to match item in list to db, not check db in list

Comment: @Hooting: I'm not sure what your problem is, it solves the task.

Comment: @matteo: amended the answer.

Comment: Instead of using `str.split` you can use `os.path.split` or even `os.path.basename`, both of which are portable.

Comment: with this solution, in order to find what I wanted, I *inverted* the variables of the loops.. see the edits to the question..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check against the filename without the extension, use [**`os.path.basename`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) and [**`os.path.splitext`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```
>>> from os import path
>>> s = '/home/user/modello1.sqlite'

>>> path.basename(s)
>>> 'modello1.sqlite'

>>> path.splitext(path.basename(s))
('modello1', '.sqlite')

>>> filename = path.splitext(path.basename(s))[0]
>>> filename
'modello1'
```

Using the filename:

```
>>> possibles = ['modello', 'modello1', 'modello_old', 'new_modello']
>>> for possible in possibles:
...     if possible in filename:
...         print possible, 'in', filename
modello in modello1
modello1 in modello1
```

If you just want to check whether any of the possibilities match:

```
>>> if any(possible in filename for possible in possibles):
...     print filename
modello1
```

I think I understand now that OP would want an exact match:

```
>>> if filename in possibles:
...     print filename
modello1
```

This won't match `modello`.

Comment: The last paragraph is wrong. Essentially you've reproduced the same problem.

Comment: agreed.. in this case I have 2 outputs while I need just **modello1**

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I haven't reproduced the problem. I've highlighted that two values match, and I've given the filename they're matching against. If they just want the filename, I've added an example.

Comment: @PeterWood: You have a peculiar way of interpreting those true words. I don't know what to say. The OP's original code also highlighted the two values that match, and that was his *problem*. BTW your fresh match checking code suffers from the same problem - it will find a partial match.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I hadn't understood, I thought they wanted a partial match.They want an exact match. But really I suspect they just want the filename.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
db_basename = os.path.basename(db)
db_basename = os.path.splitext(db_basename)[0] # remove extension
```

use `os` to get file name

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
for i in l:
    if '/'+i+'.' in db:
        print i
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.